# Python decorator for Django file based caching

Tags: python, django, caching, decorator

Imagine I have a client with a specific client ID. For that client a do expensive calculations that set `self.A`, `self.B` and `self.C`.

I also have a file based cache to save all of that for future retrieval. one solution would be having methods like this:

```
def save(self):
    cache.set(self.ID + 'A',self.A)
    cache.set(self.ID + 'B',self.B)
    cache.set(self.ID + 'C',self.C)

def get(self):
    self.A = cache.get(self.ID + 'A')
    if not self.A:
        redo_the_calculation
```

etc...

I want to be able to this with something like a property decorator that is general for every property of an object, something that by using a string composed of the (client's ID + the property name) as the key, tries to get it from the cache and if it doesn't exist recalculates it and puts in the cache. In the end I would like to just be able to do:

```
@caching_decorator
def A(self):
    calculate the value of A here
```

Is this possible? If so, can anyone give me pointers on how to create such a decorator? Thank you

Comment: Do you know there are no other arguments than `self`? Do you know whether the return values are always (de)serializable in some format like pickle or json?